# The Cantor set and its equivalents.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity, cantor-set

Let $(\{0,1 \}^ {\mathbb {N}},d)$ be a metric space, where $$d((a_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}},(b_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}})=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{|x_{n}-y_{n}|}{2^{n}}},\phantom{a}\forall (a_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}},(b_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\{0,1 \}^ {\mathbb {N}}.$$ Remember that the metric generated by d matches the product topology and $\{0,1\}$ s a discrete space.

Let $ f \colon \{0,1 \}^ {\mathbb {N}} \to [0,1] $ be a function given by

$$ f ((a_{i})_{i \in \mathbb {N}}) = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{2a_{i}}{3 ^{i}}}, \phantom {a} \forall (a_{i}) _{i \in \mathbb {N}} \in \{0,1 \} ^{\mathbb {N}}. $$

f is a continuous function, where $$\mathcal{Z}=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}{Z_{n}}$$ and $$Z_{n}=Z_{n-1}\setminus{\bigcup_{i=1}^{\dfrac{3^{n}-1}{2}}{\left(\dfrac{2i-1}{3^{n}},\dfrac{2i}{3^{n}}\right)}},\phantom{a}\forall n\geq 2.$$

Show that:

(1) f is well defined;

(2) f is injective;

(3) f is continuous;

(4) $f(\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}})=\mathcal{Z}.$

Attempt: Notice that

(1) Let $x=(a_{i})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\in\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ be. Then
\begin{align*}
        f(x)&\leq \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{2}{3^{i}}}\\
        &=\dfrac{2}{3}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{1}{3^{i}}}\\
        &=\dfrac{2}{3}\dfrac{1}{\left(1-\dfrac{1}{3}\right)}\\
        &=\frac{2}{3}\dfrac{3}{2}\\
        &=1
\end{align*}

(2) Let $x=(a_{i})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\in\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}},\phantom{a}y=(b_{i})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\in\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}\in\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ be. Let's suppose $f(x)=f(y).$ Let's see what $a_{i}=b_{i},\phantom{a}\forall i\in\mathbb{N}.$ Then
\begin{align*}
        f(x)=f(y)&\Longleftrightarrow f(x)-f(y)=0\\
        &\Longleftrightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{2(a_{i}-b_{i})}{3^{i}}}=0\\
        &\Longleftrightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{(a_{i}-b_{i})}{3^{i}}}=0.\tag{1}
\end{align*}
Let $c_{i}=a_{i}-b_{i},\phantom{a}\forall i\in\mathbb{N}.$ With the above, you can prove that $c_{i}=0,\phantom{a}\forall i\in\mathbb{N}.$

(3) Let $x=(a_{i})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\in\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $\epsilon>0$ be. By archimedean property, there is $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\dfrac{1}{2^{k}}<\epsilon.$ Let 
\begin{equation}
         \mathcal{C}=\bigcap_{i=1}^{k}{\pi_{i}^{-1}(\{a_{i}\})}.\tag{*}
\end{equation}
be. Then

(I) $\mathcal{C}$ is open, being a finite intersection of open;

(II) $x\in\mathcal{C}.$

By (I) and (II), there is $\delta>0$ such that $$\mathcal{B}_{d}(x,\delta)\subseteq{\mathcal{C}}.$$ Then $$f(\mathcal{B}_{d}(x,\delta))\subseteq{\mathcal{B}\left(f(x),\dfrac{1}{2^{k}}\right)}.$$

(4) I don't know how to prove that...

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Use m-test for continuity.

Comment: @HamidEnki What is the m-test for continuity? Do not know him.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test

Comment: @HamidEnki In my case, what would be the sequence of functions $ f_{n} (x) $?

Comment: For continuity you have to specify a metric or at least a  topology on the domain .

Comment: $f_n(\{a_i\})=a_n/3^n \leq 1/3^n$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I just corrected what I wrote above.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $d((a_i),(b_i))< \frac 1 {2^{N}}$ implies  $a_1=b_1,a_2=b_2,...,a_N=b_N$. This implies $|f(a_i)-f(b_i)| \leq \sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{\infty} \frac 2 {3^{i}}=\frac 1 {3^{N}}$.

Comment: Is this proposition true?

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to [Show that the Cantor space is homeomorphic to the Cantor set, thought of as a subspace of $\left[0,1\right]$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3526560). Based on that, the only thing that has to be verified is that the metric $d$ induces the product topology on $X  = \{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ (where $\{0,1\}$ has the discrete topology). This is well-known, see [Show that the countable product of metric spaces is metrizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/361778).